# Is it safe to split the Windows 7 system partition created by bootcamp on mac book pro?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I have just installed **Windows 7** on my **Mac Book Pro** using bootcamp.

As you might aware, bootcamp can only create **single** Windows partition along side Mac OS partition.

But now I want to be able to **split** that single Windows system partition into multiple NTFS partitions (well recognizable by Windows) to **separate** my data from system files.
Since this on **mac based hardware**, I was wondering if there could be any harm.

Has anyone ever tried to do this?

Can I create such partition **safely** using built-in Windows 7 disk management utility Or any other good partitioning tool such as GParted?

Comment: One more thing I want to add is, I want to create separate partitions without loosing existing Windows 7 system installation.

Comment: Would be a whole lot safer to use VMs. Golden rule - never let Windows touch the partition structure on a Mac. It simply does not understand how it's being fooled into thinking it's on an MBR disk

Comment: I've thought of using VM but dropped out that option since I tend to perform heavy processing(like creating large 3D models on Autocad etc). I don't think Windows will be able to perform better inside VM due to resource restriction.

Comment: This won't be exactly the same as your situation, but see this reply from the very clever klanomoath for how to approach a similar situation… which might also clarify why I mentioned trying VMs ;-) http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221691/85275

Comment: You have not given enough information to answer your question. Did you install Windows 7 in EFI/GPT or BIOS/MBR mode?

Answer (score -1):

I think, as long as your Windows partition is large enough, you could easily do that. I am far from a Mac expert and I haven't tested this yet, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.